# barra de navegación

Tags: html, css, jsp

Estoy realizando una app web. Intento hacer una barra de navegación pero esta no es fija. Este es su código:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="row" id="green-bar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">                    

                    <a href="http://www.utpuebla.edu.mx/" >
                        <div class="col-md-2" id="img-iso">
                            <img src="../images/general/logo2.png" class="img-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10" >
                            <h2>Universidad Tecnológica de Puebla</h2>
                            <h4>Educación para el progreso social</h4>
                        </div>                                        
                    </a>
                </div>  
            </div>           
        </div><!-- cierra green-bar -->

        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul  class = "nav nav-tabs" > 
                    <li  role= "presentation"  class= "active" ><a  href= "#" > Home </a></li> 
                    <li  role= "presentation" ><a  href= "../index.jsp" > Profile </a></li> 
                    <li  role= "presentation" ><a  href= "../newhtml.html" > Messages </a></li> 
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- cierrra row -->

    </nav><!-- cierra navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top -->
</div><!-- cierra container fluid -->
```

Como no es fija, cuando intento agregar más contenido a la página la barra de navegación evita que este se visualice ya que se pone por encima. ¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo? Intenté poner un margin-bottom pero cuando lo pruebo en otros dispositivos se mueve todo.

Comment: Tiene que quedar pegada a la parte superior de la ventana?

Comment: mm bueno mi objetivo es una barra estilo facebook que se mueve conforme bajas la pagina, eso intento conseguir o como ? no te entiendo jeje

Comment: Eso se llama `sticky navbar`, consulta en google como resolverlo, si estás usando bootstrap puedes revisar la documentación, en foundation antes funcionaba con la clase `sticky`, pero ahora se tiraron eso :'(

Comment: En el código que has puesto no se ve el problema ¿Puedes poner todo el código necesario para reproducir el error?

Answer (score 2):

Prueba a añadirle un padding-top al body.

```
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

He puesto 70px, pero debes poner un poco mas de la altura que tenga tu navbar.